# How to specify expected return values?

Tags: rspec, expectations

I'm new to RSpec and as I was writing a spec test I came across a problem where the spec tests are passing even though the return values are different than what I specified in my expectations. For example:

```
  @q= Query.new
  @q.should_receive(:number_to_name).with(0).and_return("no such boro") 
  @q.number_to_name(0)
```

This passes even though the Query.number_to_name is returning a different value when I call it with 0. I don't understand what to make of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`should_receive` is part of rspec's mocking tools.

```
@q.should_receive(:number_to_name).with(0).and_return("no such boro")
```

You are mocking `number_to_name` on `@q`, setting an expectation that `number_to_name` will be called with an argument of `0` and that the mock will return `"no such boro"`. Executing `@q.number_to_name(0)` then satisfies that expectation by calling the mock. Your implementation of `number_to_name` has never been called and is not being tested.

Comment: Downvoting because this does not answer the original question, the question was how to specify expected value. And you just explained why example code doesn't work.